# Where is the source code of installed packages?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlesim, source, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Kinetic and it sits is the `/opt/ros/kinetic/` folder which has the following structure:

```
.
├── bin
├── env.sh
├── etc
├── include
├── lib
├── setup.bash
├── setup.sh
├── _setup_util.py
├── setup.zsh
└── share
```

Now suppose I want to view the source code which makes `rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key` possible. It is a node of the `turtlesim` package, so I navigate to this package using `roscd turtlesim`. This puts me into the directory `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlesim`, which has the following files:

```
.
├── cmake
├── images
├── msg
├── package.xml
└── srv
```

The actual `.cpp` source files are nowhere to be found! How can I view the source files for a given package? `turtlesim` is just an example, there are of course other packages whose source I'm interested in looking at.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246775/where-is-the-source-code-of-installed-packages?/) by [danyloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28384/danylom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-10-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can retrive path to sources of specific package by typing `roslocate uri <package_name>`, for more information about roslocate see [reference](http://wiki.ros.org/roslocate).

Getting the sources for **turtlesim** can be done by: `git clone $(roslocate uri turtlesim 2> /dev/null | awk '/https/')`

---

Originally posted by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) with karma: 290 on 2016-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danyloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28384/danylom/) on 2016-10-30**:
Thanks, this worked for me!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-30**:
This works, but note that you don't necessarily get the sources that were used to build the (debian) pkg that you installed. `git clone <url>` checks out whatever the repository has configured as the default `HEAD`, while `apt-get source $pkg` downloads a tarball for a specific version.

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2016-10-30**:
I agree with @gvdhoorn 100 percent. If you download sources by above command, you'll get devel (it means develop) branch (branch set as main for this specyfic repository e.g. kinetic-devel), not released sources (based on https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_tutorials-release debian package).

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2016-10-30**:
So, if you choose this approach, you should check the branch of downloaded repository to make sure you are on right (for kinetic call: `git checkout kinetic-devel`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-30**:
If you really want the specific version of the sources used to build a pkg, checking out the 'devel branch' corresponding to your ROS distribution is not enough. You'd have to checkout the commit that was used to draft a release from. The repo should have been tagged. Use those.

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2016-10-30**:
Yes, i understand. A release pkg is always behind or equal/on beginning/ to a 'devel branch'. If you want download the latest sources with 'fixes/features', using command based on a roslocate is appropriate. Otherwise, `apt-get source $pkg_name` is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've installed ROS Kinetic using the binary debian distribution, then the sources are not installed. Only the binaries (ie: the *nodes*) and any other related artefacts (launch files, urdf/xacros, etc). What is installed is down to the developers btw: they have to include CMake `install(..)` directives in their `CMakeLists.txt` for whatever they want to be included in the binary distribution(s).

Retrieving the sources for a particular package is relatively easy, using `apt-get source $pkg_name`. You have update your `apt` configuration slightly though.

See ["apt-get source" for packages.ros.org?](http://answers.ros.org/question/12478) for how to do this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6